# how to resolve domain name issue in spring microservice

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, microservices

I just started with spring boot microservice and I got this error even when I have configured that it should use ip address in the services of my aplication.yaml files. Here is the error message that I am getting.

```
2023-12-21T15:52:51.023-08:00 ERROR 11356 --- [department-service] [nio-8081-exec-8] [                                                 ] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'METEORLOLOGIST.mshome.net' [A(1)] after 2 queries ] with root cause

io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverTimeoutException: [5997: /192.168.254.72:53] DefaultDnsQuestion(METEORLOLOGIST.mshome.net. IN CNAME) query '5997' via UDP timed out after 5000 milliseconds (no stack trace available)

2023-12-21T15:56:08.211-08:00  INFO 11356 --- [department-service] [trap-executor-0] [                                                 ] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration

This is how I configured my application.yaml files

department-service.yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: department-service
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:http://localhost:8088"

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address=true:

In my config project I have this under department-service.yaml
server:
  port: 8081

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0

And in my service-registry I have this
server:
  port: 8761

spring:
  application:
    name: service-registry

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    hostname: localhost

  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```